# Dashboards in sharepoint 2010

Tags: performance, performancepoint

There is a need to build several custom "dashboards". Dashboards contains a lot of information for the user about the process. We whish to have several dashboards for several departments and user groups. These must have custom fields and information with filters and search posibilities. How do we build them? What about the security questions? Not everyone may access all dashboards or one of them.

Obviosly this would be hard to explain in one answer, but at least the basics of what I need would be helpful.

Comment: What data do you want in there? Have you hired a Business Intelligence consultant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not hiring a consultant to do this work for you, I suggest reading through a couple of books on the capabilities and configuration of SharePoint Business Intelligence. Here's a couple of examples:

[Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Business Intelligence Unleashed](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-SharePoint-Business-Intelligence-Unleashed/dp/0672335514/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1327072543&sr=8-1)

[Pro SharePoint 2010 Business Intelligence Solutions](http://www.amazon.co.uk/SharePoint-2010-Business-Intelligence-Solutions/dp/1430232854/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1327072543&sr=8-4)